# $∂(A\cup B)$ is a subset of $∂A \cup ∂B$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

Please let me know if you think my proof of the above is correct. ($∂A$ denotes the boundary of $A$).

Suppose $\vec{x}\in ∂(A\cup B)$. Then $\vec{x}\in \overline{A \cup B}=\bar{A}\cup\bar{B}$ and $B_\varepsilon(\vec{x}) \cap (\bar{A}\cap \bar{B})\ne \emptyset\ne B_\varepsilon(\vec{x})\cap (\bar{A}\cup\bar{B})^c$. All the above implies that $\vec{x}\in ∂A$ or $\vec{x}\in ∂B$. Thus $\vec{x}\in ∂A\cup ∂B$.

I'm in a little bit of a doubt about the rigor of this proof.

Comment: $B_\varepsilon(\vec{x}) \cap (\bar{A}\cap \bar{B})\ne \emptyset\ne B_\varepsilon(\vec{x})\cap (\bar{A}\cup\bar{B})^c$ does not imply $\vec{x}\in ∂A\cup ∂B$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is right. A better proof is as 
\begin{align}
\partial(A\cup B)&=\overline{A\cup B}\cap \overline{(A\cup B)^c}
\\
&=(\overline{A}\cup \overline{B}) \cap \overline{A^c\cap B^c}
\\
&=(\overline{A}\cap \overline{A^c\cap B^c})\cup (\overline{B} \cap \overline{A^c\cap B^c})
\\
&\subset(\overline{A}\cap \overline{A^c})\cup (\overline{B} \cap \overline{B^c})
\\
&=\partial A\cup \partial B
\end{align}

Comment: Could we also do it like this? $\partial(A\cup B) = \overline{(A\cup B)}\cap \overline{(A\cup B)^c}={(\bar{A}\cup \bar{B})}\cap {(\overline{A^c}\cap \overline{B^c})}=(\bar{A} \cap \overline{A^c})\cup (\overline{A}\cap \overline{B^c})\cup(\overline{B}\cap\overline{A^c})\cup(\overline{B}\cap \overline{B^c})\subset \partial A\cup \partial B$.

Comment: That's quite interesting. I've been trying to imagine the RHS and the LHS of this inequality, but conceptually them seem equal. Would you give a counterexample?

Comment: Normally, $\overline{A\cap B}\subset\overline{A}\cap \overline{B}$, but not equal. An example is $A=(0,1), B=(1,2)$. Then $\overline{A\cap B}=\varnothing, \overline{A}\cap \overline{B}=1$. But in your case, it is right for it only needs $\subset$.